# Wordpress: Term links skip archive page and go straight to latest post

Tags: wordpress

I am experience a strange occurrence on one of my client websites. As of last night the custom post type terms(categories) links seam to skip their natural behavior of going to their respective archive page(archive template) and instead go straight to their most recent post(single template). Does anybody know what could change the normal hierarchy behavior in such a way ? is more information is required please ask i and i will provide to the best of my ability. Thank you for taking time to look at this.

Sample of wrong behaviour: http://www.bekjempsvartarbeid.no/betong/

Clicking the "Rogaland" link should bring you to a archive listing page, but instead shows you the most recent post of that category. Notice the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it turns out the issue was related to some new conditional statements in the functions file. If anybody is curious i will explain in more detail.